# missing required architecture after upgrading to cocoapods 1.0

Tags: ios, xcode7, cocoapods, dtcoretext

I'm trying to upgrade **Cocoapods** to **version 1.0** but with the new version linking `DTCoreText` fails. 
When I try to run the project on the simulator I get

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /[...]/libDTCoreText.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /[...]/libDTCoreText.a (2 slices)
```

when I try to archive I get

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /[...]/libDTCoreText.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /[...]/libDTCoreText.a (2 slices)
```

Using my the same Podfile in a clean project everything works fine! So it must be my project, but I can't figure out what it might be.

I used

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

cleaned and deleted the Derived Data from the project with no success.

The Architectures of the Project and of the Pods are set to "Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)"

[image: Pod Architectures]

I'm using Xcode 7.3 and my Podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
project 'Classes/MEG.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'myApp' do
    pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'DTCoreText', '~> 1.6'
    pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK', '7.1.0'
    pod 'DCIntrospect-ARC'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
    pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout'
    pod 'BDBOAuth1Manager', '~> 1.5.0'
    pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.4'
    pod 'Masonry', '~> 0.6'
    pod 'RSKImageCropper', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2/SNS', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~> 6.0'
    pod 'SKTagView', '~> 0.0'
    pod 'PSTAlertController', '~> 1.2'
    pod 'UITextView+Placeholder', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'MWFeedParser', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'tarkit', '~> 0.1'
    pod 'XMPPFramework', '3.6.5'
    pod 'XMLDictionary', '~> 1.4'
    pod 'NewRelicAgent', '~> 5.6'
    pod 'NHNetworkTime', '~> 1.6'

    target 'myApp Tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.2'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I had an old version of `libDTCoreText.a` lying around in my project folder.

Even though this file wasn't referenced anywhere in the project, cocoapods tried to link it. Xcode was probably meant to search for `libDTCoreText.a` within the cocoapods library, but found it in the project folder first as this is also listed in the library search paths.

Anyway, removing the file fixed the issue.